# How to customize the dashboard chart and test steps in Extent Report 5

Tags: selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

In my automation project (Selenium / Java), I am using Extent report version 5 and I have customized it to some extent.
The extent report is binded to ITestListener. After initializing and creating test - I have created 3 different nodes -
One for showcasing test input data, one for output data and another for showing test case meta data info.

The project consists of 3 test cases and 3 different nodes -

Two issues I observed and want to rectify is:

1. I am seeing the "pass" label for every node. Since I have 3 nodes created, it shows "pass" 3 times for each test case.
2. On the Dashboard, the passed steps shows 9 (due to the 3 nodes showing "pass" on each TC).
   In fact, it should be 3? (or) may be some other meaningful count which indicates number of steps passed in total from all 3 TCs?

[image: Test Case execution steps][image: Report Dashboard]